# Spring RestController handle Get Request with Body values

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data

i currently develop an experimental prototype an wanted to ask if there is a way to accept a response body in a get request.

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, path="/stair/shippingorders", produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> getShippingOrder(@RequestBody JsonNode request) throws JsonProcessingException, IOException{
    log.info("get body: " + request);

    // do stuff
    return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
}
```

the test should looks something like this

```
@Test
public void shouldAcceptRequestBodyinGetRequest() {

    JSONObject body = new JSONObject();
    body.appendField("stuff", "{}");
    HttpEntity<JSONObject> entity = new HttpEntity<JSONObject>(body);

    ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange(GET_URL,HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class );

    assertNotNull(result);
}
```

Comment: Why do you want a response body in request mapping?

Comment: I have several micro services that are loosely connected(REST). They send the Request and its content to other micro services (autonomous) depending on the content of the request. As well as the output. So a micro service changed the content and depending of (for example the state "paid") it is sendend to a different service that includes some other embedded resources for the response... With POST it's working fine but with get I have to include the stuff like resource ids as get params. It's just a prototype implementation ...so I can renounce of code an control flow of the System

Answer (score 1):

GET method doesn't support body, hence it won't be possible to send body as part of request. The common practice is to use POST instead